HuggingFace Trainer - why it asks for wandb API key?
Tried to run PEFT as in YouTube-Blog/LLMs/fine-tuning
/ft-example.ipynb in Google Colab.
# define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir= model_checkpoint + "-lora-text-classification",
    learning_rate=lr,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    num_train_epochs=num_epochs,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    # report_to=None
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset["validation"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator, 
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
trainer.train()

It asks for a wandb login API key, but Why?
wandb: WARNING The `run_name` is currently set to the same value as `TrainingArguments.output_dir`. If this was not intended, please specify a different run name by setting the `TrainingArguments.run_name` parameter.
wandb: Using wandb-core as the SDK backend. Please refer to https://wandb.me/wandb-core for more information.
wandb: Logging into wandb.ai. (Learn how to deploy a W&B server locally: https://wandb.me/wandb-server)
wandb: You can find your API key in your browser here: https://wandb.ai/authorize
wandb: Paste an API key from your profile and hit enter, or press ctrl+c to quit:

According to class transformers.TrainingArguments, the report_to argument is None by default. Then, it should not try to connect to wandb.

According to documentation

report_to (str or List[str], optional, defaults to "all")

Try to pass
report_to="none"

